# Modify Html for Additional Information Tab

Tags: template, product-attribute, additional-information

I am trying to modify how the additional information is displayed for a theme:

http://prntscr.com/47t6uk

I want to wrap the information in span tags so I can access them with jquery and also potentially move the whole thing to be rendered elsewhere but am not sure where this is actually being rendered. Where can I find the files generating this html?

Comment: Use the force of the Template path hints Luke: http://www.pauldonnelly.net/magento-turning-on-template-path-hints/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning on path hints as per Marius's comment above allowed me to see where this was getting rendered.

To do so in case in the future his link is dead:

```
How to turn on Template Path Hints?

Open the admin control panel
Open the system tab and select configuration
Select Main Website or Name of your website (NOT DEFAULT CONFIG) from the Current Configuration Scope drop down
Select Developer on the left sidebar
Open the Debug drop down
Set Template Path Hints To Yes
Click on Save Config to save down your changes
```

After that you should be able to load the page you are trying to see the rendered parts for and it will show you where it is rendered.